# improper integral of exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have a problem calculating improper integrals, this one for example, can you please help me solve it?
$$\int_0^\infty t^3(e^{-t^2})dt$$
thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: never mind! solved it ^^ they had a mistake in the solution..

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: Let $u = t^2, t^3dt = t^2\cdot tdt$. Can you continue?

Comment: they got to that part in the book.. yet I don't quite understand how to get there...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write $u = t^2$, so that ${\rm d}u = 2t\,{\rm d}t$. Rewrite $t^3e^{-t^2}$ as $-\frac{1}{2}(-2t)t^2e^{-t^2}$ , apply the substituition and integrate by parts.

Comment: I have two questions regarding that, first why is it legit to rewrite the function this way?? and why can I integrate by parts here? I thought I only can do that if I have addition or minus..

Comment: @Marie Integration by parts is specifically when you are trying to integrate a product of functions, like $t^3$ multiplied by $e^{-t^{2}}$. If you were trying to integrate the sum of $t^3$ and $e^{-t^{2}}$, you could integrate each separately to get $\left[\frac{t^4}{4}\right]_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty e^{-t^{2}}dt$

Comment: @Marie, we can rewrite the function like this for the same reasons that $(-1/2)\cdot(-2) = 1$ and $t^3 = t\cdot t^2$. Both expressions $t^3e^{-t^2}$ and $(-1/2)(-2t)t^2e^{-t^2}$ are equal. About integration by parts, I think graydad's explanation is good.

Answer (score 0):

By setting $t=\sqrt{u}$ we have $dt = \frac{1}{2}u^{-1/2}\,du$ and:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^3 e^{-t^2}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty} u e^{-u}\,du = \frac{1}{2}\left.(u+1)e^{-u}\right|_{0}^{+\infty}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}.$$